# "No visible @interface declares the selector" error

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, xcode4.5

I inserted an image view in my view controller but dont actually know how to display image on it.

I tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


id path = @"http://thestylishdog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/cute-dog2.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImageView *firstImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
}
```

But then it says that 'No visible @interface for UIimage declares the selector initwithData:cache'

I tried adding this line to the .h file but does not work either:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *firstImage;
```

I know that the last step would be to assign that .h create class to the UIimage in the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use try this code to add image from the path in your `imageview`

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thestylishdog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/cute-dog2.jpg"];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Don't forget to show your `imageView` as outlet to `xib` if you are adding through GUI otherwise add it to your view as `subview`

Comment: I cant get it to appear on the outlets for me to be able to drag it in the xbi :( do I need to synthesize imageView or something?

Comment: you need to drag the UIImageView on the xib and then using connection inspector connect it with the outlet in the code where you declare the UIImageView as outlet, something like this in your code `@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;`

Comment: Alright thanks! Steps done! I am getting this error though: Use of undeclared identifier imageView, did you mean _imageView. waat?

Comment: this imageView is same imageView you declare , you could synthesize in your `.m` class and use it like `self.imageView`

Comment: `@synthesize imageView = _imageView;` and then `- (void)configureView
{self.imageView = self.imageView;}` like that?

Comment: basically if you are using latest version of xcode and iOS you don't need to synthesize it, but if you are using older then you could synthesize it like this `@synthesize imageview;` thats it, and use the imageview in your code like this `self.imageView` no need of configure view? why you doing that ? `self.imageView = self.imageView;` you should not do this

Comment: yep, got latest version. so i just drop `self.imageView` in any line of the `.m` file?

Comment: Yea when you adding image in your imageview as in my answer you should use self.imageView

Answer (score 1):

Try `[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];`  you can cache using an `NSCachedURLResponse` for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to load images from URLs:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]]];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

But this will block your app until your image loads. It's best to load your images asynchronously when using images from the web. If the images are downloaded in a different thread user can keep interacting with the app. You can check this example from apple about lazy loading images: [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Or you can checkout this tutorial for async image download:
[UItables with downloaded images](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/)

Comment: thanks! I tried the first part but then i get: Unused variable 'imageView'. How can I display it in the Outlets to be able to drag it to the uiimageview in the xib file?

Comment: First you have to create an outlet (crtl drag from the imageview in your xib to the .h file of the controller). Then you create the `UIImage *image` (first line). After that you just set the fetched image to the outlet with `[imageViewOutlet setImage:image];`